# CSS: el Height 100vh no funciona correctamente

Tags: html, css

En CSS hay una manera de pillar toda la altura del documento html que es 100vw, y no me esta pillando toda la altura correctamente.

El CSS se ve así:

```
#menu{
    background-color: #252525 !important; 
    height: 100vw;
}
```

Y la pagina se ve así:

Sin el inspeccionar elemento abierto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Con el inspeccionar elemento abierto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al añadir otro registro via formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podria solucionarlo poniendo 102vw, pero igualmente al añadir un nuevo registro no me pillarla el 100%, como podría resolver este problema?

La estructura del archivo es la siguiente:

```
<body>
            <div class="bg-dark dk" id="wrap">

                <div id="top">
                    @include('cms.public.includes.header') <!-- TOP DIV -->
                </div>

                <div id="left"> <!-- ESTE ES EL DIV QUE QUIERO APLICAR EL ESTILO CSS -->
                            @include('cms.public.includes.left') <!-- LEFT DIFT -->
                </div>

                <div id="content">

                    @yield('content')

                </div>

                <div id="right" class="onoffcanvas is-right is-fixed bg-light" aria-expanded=false>

                        @include('cms.public.includes.header')                   

                </div>
            </div>

            <footer class="footer">
                @include('cms.public.includes.footer') <!-- FOOTER -->
            </footer>

</body>
```

Al aplicar el estilo al div id="left" obtengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: Para la altura no se utilizaba vh?

Comment: Cierto, si pongo VH queda mucho mas arriba el menu de la izquierda.

Comment: Pilla toda la altura de la pantalla, pero no del documento entero.

Answer (score 2):

Te estás confundiendo de unidades:

`100vw` = 100% del ancho del *viewport*, no del documento.

`100vh` = 100% de la altura del *viewport*, no del documento.

El viewport es la parte visible del documento, por lo que su tamaño viene a ser lo mismo que `window.innerHeight * window.innerWidth`

Te pongo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo, usando flexbox:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  min-height: 100vh; /*Como mínimo, el documento ocupará toda la pantalla*/
}
#container > div {
  width: 50%;
  
}
div.left {
  background-color: #252525;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li> 1</li>
      <li> 2</li>
      <li> 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum... bla bla bla bla</p>
    <p>En un lugar de la Mancha de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum... bla bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @PabloLozano cual sería la manera de indicar el 100% de altura del documento entonces?

Comment: No hay un método directo, pero te he añadido una forma de enfocar el asunto

Comment: El div menu, esta dentro de un div con id="left" que esta dentro del body. Si aplico el color al div id="left" obtengo el mismo resultado. No veo del todo claro cual seria la manera correcta.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta para que veas la estructura del archivo @PabloLozano

Comment: Por qué no aplicar el color a #wrap?

Comment: Entonces se aplicara el color a todos los divs que tiene dentro, y solo quiero que se aplique a el div left. En su defecto supongo que si, puedo aplicarlo al #wrap, y aplicar CSS con !important a la tabla y demás que tengo, pero yo lo vería como 'camuflar' el problema. @PabloLozano

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer a ver qué te parece lo que he puesto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65479/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-pablo-lozano).

Answer (score 0):

Una técnica es dándole al body y al html un alto (Sip, la etiqueta html tambien puede tener un alto) De esta forma, tu mismo estás estableciendo el alto del documento antes de empezar a trabajar con el con tu código.

```
.html,body{
    height:100vh;
}
```