# Como puedo hacer que este carrusel ocupe el 100 del ancho de la pantalla?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Tengo este codigo con un carrusel con bootstrap 5, necesito que el carrusel abarque el 100 del alto de la pantalla pero al utilizar las clases h-100 no las respeta, igual trate de utilizar las clases "position-relative" en el contenedor con la clase col-lg-12 y un h-100 en el contenedor con la clase carousel-inner, pero no las respeta. Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="height: 100vh;">
                <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" >
                        <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
                            <img src="images/soluciones/ruta-1.png" class="d-block img-fluid h-100 px-5 px-lg-5"
                                alt="...">

                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                            <img src="images/soluciones/ruta-2.png" class="d-block img-fluid h-100 px-5 px-lg-5"
                                alt="...">

                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="images/soluciones/ruta-3.png" class="d-block img-fluid h-100 px-5 px-lg-5"
                                alt="...">

                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="images/soluciones/ruta-4.png" class="d-block img-fluid h-100 px-5 px-lg-5"
                                alt="...">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev margen-carrusel-soluciones-l" type="button"
                        data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next margen-carrusel-soluciones-r" type="button"
                        data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dale a `<body>` un alto de **100vh** y después agrégale a cada nodo hijo (descendientes tanto directos como indirectos) la clase **h-100**, esto es necesario porque **h-100** usa como referencia el tamaño de su padre inmediato para ocupar todo su alto, entonces necesitas trasladar ese tamaño por todos los niveles del arbol:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="height: 100vh;">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-lg-12 h-100">
      <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide h-100" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
          <div class="carousel-item active h-100" data-bs-interval="10000">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/b7mn492/presentacion-pc-7.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid h-100 px-5 px-lg-5" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/P18zwgH/presentacion-pc-3.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid h-100 px-5 px-lg-5" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item h-100">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yhYVn4v/presentacion-pc-4.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid h-100 px-5 px-lg-5" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item h-100">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VJsdYPC/vacio-cocido.png" class="d-block img-fluid h-100 px-5 px-lg-5" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev margen-carrusel-soluciones-l" type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next margen-carrusel-soluciones-r" type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Una pregunta de SO en ingles interesante sobre este tema: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003484/i-need-to-fix-bootstrap-h-100-class-it-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/), las clases **h-100** y **w-100** hacen que un elemento tenga el 100% de la altura y el ancho de su elemento padre, respectivamente. Sin embargo, si el elemento padre no tiene una altura definida, estas clases no tendrán ningún efecto.

Una posible solución sería aplicar la clase **h-100** a un elemento padre que tenga una altura definida. Por ejemplo, podrías intentar aplicar la clase **h-100** a un elemento div que envuelva todo el carrusel:

```
<div class="h-100">
   <div class="row">
       <!-- El resto de tu código de carrusel aquí -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Tema relacionado: [CSS: el Height 100vh no funciona correctamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101638/css-el-height-100vh-no-funciona-correctamente)